# "Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." being thrown with no obvious reason as to why

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to C# and I'm following the guide posted on tutorialspoint. I am following their code but not exactly because I don't just want to copy and paste what they have, I want to understand the code I'm writing. So their code runs fine, but mine throws the error shown in the title and I have no idea why. I don't see how my code isn't working but theirs is. Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Learning
{
    class Rectangle
    {
        double length;
        double width;

        public void setDimensions()
        {
            length = 4.5;
            width = 3.5;
        }

        public double getArea()
        {
            return length * width;
        }

        public void displayInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length: {0)", length);
            Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
            Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", getArea());
        }
    }

    class ExecRect
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.setDimensions();
            r.displayInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's their code:

```
using System;

namespace RectangleApplication {
   class Rectangle {
      
      // member variables
      double length;
      double width;
      
      public void Acceptdetails() {
         length = 4.5;    
         width = 3.5;
      }
      public double GetArea() {
         return length * width; 
      }
      public void Display() {
         Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
         Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
         Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
      }
   }
   class ExecuteRectangle {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
         Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
         r.Acceptdetails();
         r.Display();
         Console.ReadLine(); 
      }
   }
}
```

Where is it that I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Lol, stupud mistake. Closed the curly braces with a ) instead of } on line 23. Thanks!

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown on? That's quite useful information to home in on the source of the issue.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace after the `0` in the string at `Console.WriteLine("Length: {0)", length);` You have a parenthesis instead.

Comment: Note that `Console.WriteLine($"Length: {length}")` would not allow for the same mistake, as interpolated strings are checked at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to close your braces at method `displayInfo` with `"Length: {0)", length`.

I suggest you use string interpolation with `Console.WriteLine($"Length: {length}")`